# Create dash plotly stack bar chart that has interactive x axis based on dropdown values

Tags: python, callback, visualization, plotly-dash

I am writing a dash plotly python code that draws a stack barchart for each county's sanitation indicators like below.

[image]

However, I cannot seem to find the correct way to ensure the stacked bar chart increments the counties on the x axis based on the dropdown values ie. if I select 5 values in the dropdown, the stack barchart should show 5 stacked barcharts for each county (eg. Baringo, Kisumu, Mombasa, Nairobi, Nyeri). Likewise, if I narrow down the counties in the dropdown to just 2, the plotly graph should show just two stacked bars for each county (eg. Bomet, Kiambu).

All the files used on the code are available in this [github repository](https://github.com/sammigachuhi/dash_plotly_projects.git), but the name of the python file is `stack_barchart.py`. The code in the aformentioned `.py` file is as below:

```
# Import the necessary packages
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html, Input, Output

df = pd.read_csv('sanitation_long2.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('human_waste_filtered.csv')
df2 = df2[['County', 'Conventional Households', 'Main Sewer', 'Septic tank', 'Cess pool', 'VIP Latrine',
           'Pit latrine covered', 'Pit Latrine uncovered', 'Bucket latrine', 'Open/ Bush', 'Bio-septic tank/ Biodigester', 'Not Stated']]

# Initialize the app
app = Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2(children="Pie chart showing human waste disposal as proportion of conventional households (Kenya 2019 census)"),

    # Create dropdown
    dcc.Dropdown([name for name in df.County], id='selected_county', multi=True),

    # Create stack bar graph/chart
    dcc.Graph(figure={}, id='controls-and-graph'),

    # Create filterable datatable
    dash_table.DataTable(columns= [
        {'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df2.columns
    ],
        data=df2.to_dict('records'),
        filter_action='native',
        sort_action='native',
        page_size=5),

    # Create download button
    html.Div([
        html.Button("Download CSV", id='btn-csv'),
        dcc.Download(id='download-dataframe-csv')
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('controls-and-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('selected_county', 'value'),
)
def update_graph(dropdown_choices):
    dff = df[df.County == dropdown_choices]
    fig = px.bar(dff, x='County', y='value', color='indicator')
    return fig

# Function to show and download dataframe
@app.callback(
    Output('download-dataframe-csv', 'data'),
    Input('btn-csv', 'n-clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def func(n_clicks):
    return dcc.send_data_frame(df2.to_csv, 'mydf.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I tried playing around with the `def update_graph()` code block values, including following the callback examples from [here](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks). However, they only made the problem more complex and incomprehensible. The persistent error that popped up in most tries was:

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (470,), (1,))
```

Googling the problem only brought one [solution](https://community.plotly.com/t/getting-valueerror-lengths-must-match-to-compare-when-adding-more-than-2-or-more-options-in-dropdown/41486) which referenced a medium article [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/valueerror-lengths-must-match-to-compare-when-adding-more-than-2-options-in-dropdown-3b4e0a5c77d4)
However, I couldn't seem to understand the logic of the solution.

Could someone help me have a stack bar chart plotly graph that upscales and downscales county name and their indicators based on the multi-value dropdown? For more info on dash plotly dropdowns, see this [page](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line :

```py
dff = df[df.County == dropdown_choices]
```

You want to select those counties from `df.County` that are ***in*** `dropdown_choices` (not equal). Also, because "*the truth value of a series is ambiguous in list*", we can't use the `in` operator so we have to use the function [`pandas.DataFrame.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

Note also that there is is a typo in the second callback : `"n-clicks"`  instead of `"n_clicks"`.

So you just need to fix those two callbacks :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('controls-and-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('selected_county', 'value'),
)
def update_graph(dropdown_choices):
    if isinstance(dropdown_choices, list):
        dff = df[df.County.isin(dropdown_choices)]
        fig = px.bar(dff, x='County', y='value', color='indicator')
        return fig
    return go.Figure()

# Function to show and download dataframe
@app.callback(
    Output('download-dataframe-csv', 'data'),
    Input('btn-csv', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def func(n_clicks):
    return dcc.send_data_frame(df2.to_csv, 'mydf.csv')
```